# ASP.NET Core model order by foreign field

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a table `TableA` with a foreign key to another table `TableB`. I want to get a list of `TableA` but need to order by a column of `TableB`. I want the query order by different columns which the user selected.

TableA:

```
class TableA 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TableBId { get; set; }
    public DateTime RecordDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public TableB TableB { get; set; }
}
```

TableB:

class TableB 
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set }
   }

Controller method:

```
string SortField = "TableB.Description";
string Order = "A";
var DataSet = from q in DB.TableA.Include(x => x.TableB) select q;

if (Order == "A")
{
    DataSet = DataSet.OrderBy(x => EF.Property<object>(x, SortField));
}
else 
{
    DataSet = DataSet.OrderByDescending(x => EF.Property<object>(x, SortField));
}
```

Assume `SortField` is variable and may changed by user. I tested if the field name in `SortField` is in `TableA`, e.g. `Description` or `RecordDate`, the above code has no problem but exception error is raised if the SortField is from TableB.

Thank you!

Comment: `EF.Property<object>` seems wrong imho. Type on EF.Property is meant to be the type of the property, see docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-3.0

Comment: Just to test the general behavior: does it work if you replace the `EF.Property...` in the second case to a hard-coded property of B, like `x.TableB.Id`? Does `EF.Property<object>(x.TableB, SortField)` work?

Comment: Hi Markus, It's work!  Thanks a lot!  However, I would like to let user select the fields to sort (the list will display as a table in html and user click the column header the list will reload with specific order), not only the second table, may be the column from primary table, second table, ... I need to find a simple way to easily construct the LINQ query to sort and columns in the query.